# Assistance with using the XPATH functionality of Voxeo's CallXML language

Tags: php, xpath

I have a basic XML response which I have formed using a PHP script, it looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<result>
   <status>error</status>
   <message>Something has gone wrong.</message>
</result>
```

I am trying to access the message string within this XML using the XPATH functionality detailed in Voxeo's CallXML language.  The expressions and functions are listed here:

http://docs.voxeo.com/callxml/3.0/xpathexpr1_cxml30.htm#start

The documentation lists lot of ways to iterate over lists etc. but no simple functionality which would allow me to directly access the property I want in what seems like such simple XML.  I'm completely new to XPATH and must admit it doesn't make a lot of sense to me, so it could be me and not the documentation!

Comment: I don't know about Voxeo XPath engine... But the expression to select what you want is `/result/message`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code contained in this article:

Manipulate XML data with XPath and XmlDocument (C#)

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/myXPath.aspx

and use the XPath expression

/result/message

as @Alejandro said.